# Sequence with positive terms such that $\frac{4}{a_{n+1}}= \frac{3}{a_n}+\frac{{a_n}^3}{81}, n\geq1$ and $ a_1=1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

I have a sequence with positive terms such that $\frac{4}{a_{n+1}}= \frac{3}{a_n}+\frac{{a_n}^3}{81}, n\geq1$ and $ a_1=1$.
I have to check its monotonicity.
I am able to evaluate that $a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{a_n(81-{a_n}^4)}{243+{a_n}^4}$.
But to show it is an increasing sequence I need to show that $a_n<3$. I could really use some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is to prove that max of

$$f(x) = \frac{4}{\frac{3}{x}+\frac{x^3}{81}}$$ is $3$ for $x > 0$.

But

$$f'(x) = -\frac{972 (-81 + x^4)}{(243 + x^4)^2}$$

which gives max $f_{max}(3)=3$.

Because  you never reach $a_n=3$ you cannot reach $a_{n+1}=3$ either for $n < \infty$ since for all $0 < x < 3$ it is $0 < f(x) < 3$, since $3$ is the only local maximum when $x > 0$.

So $a_n$ is bounded above it is monotonic so it has the limit. Find it by solving

$$\frac{4}{x} = \frac{3}{x}+\frac{x^3}{81}$$

and the job done. The above is giving $x= \pm 3$ so it is $a_{\infty}=3$.